# L2 norm in measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in L^2(E)$ and $E$ be a measurable set. Prove that
$$\|f\|_{L^2(E)}=\sup\left\{\int_E f(x)g(x)\,dx:\|g\|_{L^2(E)}=1\right\}.$$

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you understand to be the definition of $|| f ||_{L^2(E)}$?

Comment: Use Hahn-Banach.

Comment: Use Cauchy-Schwarz and also try to find the right $g$. (No Hahn-Banach needed…)

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice of Dirk. Observe
\begin{align}
\left|\int_E f(x)g(x)\ dx \right|\leq \| f\|_{L^2(E)} \|g\|_{L^2(E)}  = \| f\|_{L^2(E)}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\sup\left\{ \int_E fg\ dx \mid \|g\|_{L^2(E)}=1  \right\} \leq \| f\|_{L^2(E)}.
\end{align}
Now, let us pick $g$ given by
\begin{align}
g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{\| f\|_{L^2(E)}}
\end{align}
then we see $\|g\|_{L^2(E)}=1$ and
\begin{align}
\int_E g(x)f(x)\ dx = \frac{1}{\|f\|_{L^2(E)}}\int_{E} |f(x)|^2\ dx = \|f\|_{L^2(E)}.  
\end{align}
Hence we have
\begin{align}
\sup\left\{ \int_E fg\ dx \mid \|g\|_{L^2(E)}=1  \right\} = \| f\|_{L^2(E)}
\end{align}
since the maximum is attained.